# mysql equivalent of IN() clause doing logical AND's instead

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table making a junction between two tables... like this:

```
id_product | id_category
-----------------
11 | 22
11 | 33
12 | 22
12 | 33
```

I want to get id_products (distinct) according to a list of searched categories IDs.

If I use the IN() clause, the list of id_categories uses a logical OR.

How can I make a SELECT query to have logical ANDs for the list of id_categ submitted??

Example: I want all the id_products belonging to category 22 *AND* 33 (and possibly 5+ more Categ. IDs)

I found this answer:
[Using MySQL IN clause as all inclusive (AND instead of OR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751361/using-mysql-in-clause-as-all-inclusive-and-instead-of-or)
...but the query is mixing more than 1 table... I only want a query on a single table, the junction one.

Comment: How can a category be equal to 22 AND 33 at the same time?

Comment: I asked the exact same question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157772/sql-query-to-find-products-matching-a-set-of-categories

Answer (score 12, accepted):

reading your link, I think it would be something like

```
select id_product 
from yourTable
where id_category in (--your List goes Here)
group by id_product 
having count(distinct id_category) = NumberOfElementsOfYourList
```

you should use = if only wants to get that id_category, but no others id_category.
If not, use >=

Comment: I changed `COUNT(distinct id_product)` to `COUNT(distinct id_category)` in your `HAVING` clause... `COUNT(distinct id_product)` will always be 1 for each id_product group.

Comment: you just saved my day, today. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id_product
from your_table
where id_category in (22, 33)
group by id_product
having count(distinct id_category) = 2
```

You can add a `having` clause that counts the found `id_category`'s. If you look for 5 IDs for instance, you have to change the  `2` in `5` in the `having` clause.