# How to write a specific MySQL query to perform a relational division/ intersect? Id est, what query do I write?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-6, relational-division

I'm having trouble understanding **how to write a specific MySQL query to perform a relational division/ intersect**. I have looked at the following links/ SO questions, but I'm still confused :

[MySQL equivalent of IN() clause doing Logical AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976559/mysql-equivalent-of-in-clause-doing-logical-ands-instead) ; [Relational Algebra : Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29) ; [Divided we Stand](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) ; [Advanced SQL : Intersect](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-intersect.html) ; [Doing INTERSECT and MINUS in MySQL](http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71) and [Alternative to INTERSECT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621382/alternative-to-intersect-in-mysql)

I attempted to adapt the SQL query shown in "Alternative to INTERSECT in MySQL", but got lost in the implementation.

*Pseudocode* :

```
Want : package.* from package WHERE package.pkid equalto package_products.pkid AND package_products.pid is_all_of (
    WANT : option_products.pid FROM option_products 
    WHERE option_products.oid = [optionID]
), // returning packages that have all of the product IDs (pids) and not just one of them.
[OptionID] = $option
```

*MySQL* (inside db_query() :

```
"SELECT package.* FROM package WHERE package.pkid = package_products.pkid && package_products.pid is_allof(".
    // What do I use in place of 'is_all_of'? How do I do an intersection/ relational division with INNER JOIN and/ or USING(pid)?
"    SELECT options_products.pid FROM options_products WHERE options_products.oid = :option
)", array(":option" => $option )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something here, but I'd say that

```
db_query("SELECT package.* FROM package 
WHERE package.pkid = package_products.pkid 
&& package_products.pid IN 
(SELECT options_products.pid FROM options_products 
WHERE options_products.oid = %d)", $option));
```

should work for you.

I have rewritten your syntax to meet Drupal 6 db_query requirements (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_query/6).

Comment: IN is an OR condition (is one of). What I'm after is an AND condition (is all of).