# Alternative to "IN" that works like "AND" instead of "OR"

Tags: mysql, sql

From my understanding, IN works like this:

```
$arrayName = array(1, 2, 3);

SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE productID IN ($arrayName)
```

is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE productID = 1 OR productID = 2 OR productID = 3
```

I'm wondering if there's a SQL function that works like IN  but uses AND in place of OR to compare to an array. Something that would expand to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE productID = 1 AND productID = 2 AND productID = 3
```

Not that it's necessary, but for context I'm simply creating a sort list for some search results that are being populated on a PHP page via jQuery. I can do what I need with PHP, I'll simply create the query dynamically depending on what options the user has selected, but I'd rather use an intelligent SQL function if possible.

***EDIT: Thanks everyone for the help. I explained my problem very poorly and you were still able to sort it out, which I appreciate. I found that someone else had asked this question more eloquently and received an answer that I can use:

[Is there something in MySQL like IN but which uses AND instead of OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860374/is-there-something-in-mysql-like-in-but-which-uses-and-instead-of-or?rq=1)

I'm trying to figure out how to accept an answer and close this but I'm having a bit of trouble...

Comment: `productID` can't be 1,2 and 3 in a single row. I understand what you want though. You need a [relational divison](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) query.

Comment: That query does not make sense, agree with @MartinSmith

Comment: If you do `$arrayName = array(1, 2, 3);` and then `"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE productID IN ($arrayName)";` in PHP, which seems the language used, you'd get the query `"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE productID IN (Array)";`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751361/using-mysql-in-clause-as-all-inclusive-and-instead-of-or

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there something in MySQL like IN but which uses AND instead of OR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860374/is-there-something-in-mysql-like-in-but-which-uses-and-instead-of-or)

Comment: @Bidbits Click on the checkmark under the right answer (on the left where the big number is with two arrows)

Comment: Thanks, got it, limits me from picking one for a certain time period. I'm amazed at how quickly everyone responded, very impressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot possibly do this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE productID = 1 AND productID = 2 AND productID = 3
```

the condition will always returns `false` because a row can have only one value on its column, the alternative way to do this is by grouping the result, ex.

```
SELECT colName
FROM tableName
WHERE productID IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY colName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT colName) = 3
```

by having a condition `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT colName) = 3`, this means that the instance of a record must be equal to the total count of parameters supplied on `IN` clause.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks a lot for the quick response. There isn't a problem with the code I'm using, I'm just an idiot at explaining things. I found another question were someone asked/answered better than I could:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860374/is-there-something-in-mysql-like-in-but-which-uses-and-instead-of-or?rq=1

Comment: You would need `COUNT(DISTINCT productID)`

Comment: @MartinSmith that's also correct if tableName allows duplicate productName which primary key is auto incremented. Actually it always depends on every situation. Anyway, thanks for the comment.Much appreciated :)

Comment: There are two ways to implement relational division, one is the above answer and the other is via joins, [which is explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2860425/4248167). According to [this test shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31102803/4248167), the join implementation has better performance and is the faster of the two implementations.

Answer (score 3):

As written, your query will produce no rows.  It is not possible for productID in a row to be equal to both 1 and 2 at the same time.

You are probably looking for a *group* of rows that contain these three products.  Say you want to find orders that have all three products.  You can use something like:

```
select orderid
from orderlines ol
group by orderid
havnig max(case when ol.productid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       max(case when ol.productid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       max(case when ol.productid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

The GROUP BY with the HAVING clause will find orders where all three products are present.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT orderid 
FROM tableName  
WHERE productID IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY orderid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT productID) = 3 --this number must match the number of unique IDs in the IN clause
```