# What is the performance difference in MySQL relational division (IN AND instead of IN OR) implementations?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Because MySQL does not have a built in relational division operator, programmers must implement their own. There are two leading examples of implementations which can be found in [this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2860425/4248167)

For posterity I'll list them below:

> ### Using GROUP BY/HAVING
>
> ---
>
> ```
> SELECT t.documentid
> FROM TABLE t
> WHERE t.termid IN (1,2,3)
> GROUP BY t.documentid
> HAVING COUNT(DISINCT t.termid) = 3
> ```
>
> The caveat is that you have to use HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT because
>   duplicates of termid being 2 for the same documentid would be a false
>   positive. And the COUNT has to equal the number of termid values in
>   the IN clause.
>
> ### Using JOINs
>
> ---
>
> ```
> SELECT t.documentid
> FROM TABLE t
> JOIN TABLE x ON x.termid = t.termid
>               AND x.termid = 1
> JOIN TABLE y ON y.termid = t.termid
>               AND y.termid = 2
> JOIN TABLE z ON z.termid = t.termid
>               AND z.termid = 3
> ```
>
> But this one can be a pain for handling criteria that changes a lot.

Of these two implementation techniques, which one would offer the best performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some improvements in the `JOIN` version; see below.

I vote for the JOIN approach for speed.  Here's how I determined it:

**HAVING, version 1**

```
mysql> FLUSH STATUS;
mysql> SELECT city
    ->     FROM us_vch200
    ->     WHERE state IN ('IL', 'MO', 'PA')
    ->     GROUP BY city
    ->     HAVING count(DISTINCT state) >= 3;
+-------------+
| city        |
+-------------+
| Springfield |
| Washington  |
+-------------+
mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_external_lock      | 2     |
| Handler_read_first         | 1     |
| Handler_read_key           | 2     |
| Handler_read_last          | 1     |
| Handler_read_next          | 4175  | -- full index scan

(etc)

+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                            |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | us_vch200 | range | state_city,city_state | city_state | 769     | NULL | 4176 | Using where; Using index for group-by (scanning) |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

The 'Extra' points out that it decided to tackle the `GROUP BY` and use `INDEX(city, state)` even though `INDEX(state, city)` might make sense.

**HAVING, version 2**

Making it switch to `INDEX(state, city)` yields:

```
mysql> FLUSH STATUS;
mysql> SELECT city
    ->     FROM us_vch200  IGNORE INDEX(city_state)
    ->     WHERE state IN ('IL', 'MO', 'PA')
    ->     GROUP BY city
    ->     HAVING count(DISTINCT state) >= 3;
+-------------+
| city        |
+-------------+
| Springfield |
| Washington  |
+-------------+
mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 2     |
| Handler_read_key           | 401   |
| Handler_read_next          | 398   |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 398   |
(etc)

+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | us_vch200 | range | state_city,city_state | state_city | 2       | NULL |  397 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
```

**JOIN**

```
mysql> SELECT x.city
    -> FROM us_vch200 x
    -> JOIN us_vch200 y ON y.city= x.city AND y.state = 'MO'
    -> JOIN us_vch200 z ON z.city= x.city AND z.state = 'PA'
    -> WHERE                                  x.state = 'IL';
+-------------+
| city        |
+-------------+
| Springfield |
| Washington  |
+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 6     |
| Handler_read_key           | 86    |
| Handler_read_next          | 87    |
(etc)    
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | y     | ref  | state_city,city_state | state_city | 2       | const              |   81 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | z     | ref  | state_city,city_state | state_city | 769     | const,world.y.city |    1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | x     | ref  | state_city,city_state | state_city | 769     | const,world.y.city |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Only `INDEX(state, city)` is needed.  The Handler numbers are the smallest for this formulation, so I deduce that it is the fastest.

Notice how the optimizer made up its own mind which table to start with, probably due to

```
+-------+----------+
| state | COUNT(*) |
+-------+----------+
| IL    |      221 |
| MO    |       81 |  -- smallest
| PA    |       96 |
+-------+----------+
```

**Conclusions**

`JOIN` (without the unnecessary `t` table) is probably the fastest.  Plus this composite index is needed:  `INDEX(state, city)`.

To translate back to your use case:

```
city --> documentid
state --> termid
```

Caveat:  YMMV because the distribution of values for documentid and termid could be quite different than the test case I used.

Comment: Excellent answer! The handler numbers really make this apparent.  Thank you!